# webrtc works on intranet but not on internet

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am working on a video call app using webrtc. My issue is that when I am connected on the same network, then the video call work fine but on a different network webrtc, there is no response. Please give me some solution. Here is the `IceServer` code snippet:

```
var iceServers = [{
            'urls': [
                'stun:webrtcweb.com:7788', // coTURN
                'stun:webrtcweb.com:7788?transport=udp', // coTURN
            ],
            'username': 'muazkh',
            'credential': 'muazkh'
        },
            {
                'urls': [
                    'turn:webrtcweb.com:7788', // coTURN 7788+8877
                    'turn:webrtcweb.com:4455?transport=udp', // restund udp

                    'turn:webrtcweb.com:8877?transport=udp', // coTURN udp
                    'turn:webrtcweb.com:8877?transport=tcp', // coTURN tcp
                ],
                'username': 'muazkh',
                'credential': 'muazkh'
            },
            {
                'urls': [
                    'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302?transport=udp',
                ]
            }
        ];
```

Comment: Please check your ICE candidates negotiation. Might be the issue if you only getting HOST candidates.

Comment: Can you please provide/attach dump from chrome://webrtc-internals/?

Comment: {
 "getUserMedia": [],
 "PeerConnections": {},
 "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36"
}